# Django how to override clean() method in a subclass of custom form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a custom form with custom validation like this:

```
class MyCustomForm(forms.Form):
    # ... form fields here

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        # ... do some cross-fields validation here

        return cleaned_data
```

Now, this form is subclassed with another form which has its own clean method.
What is the correct way to trigger both clean() methods?
At the moment, this is what I do:

```
class SubClassForm(MyCustomForm):
    # ... additional form fields here

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        # ... do some cross-fields validation for the subclass here

        # Then call the clean() method of the super  class
        super(SubClassForm, self).clean()

        # Finally, return the cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

It seems to work. However, this makes two clean() methods return `cleaned_data` which seems to me a bit odd.
Is this the correct way?

Comment: You're doing it correctly.

Comment: Looks interesting, is there a page within the documentation which explains cleaning the fields like this? or is this picked up from the source code?

Answer (score 27):

You do it well, but you should load cleaned_data from super call like this:

```
class SubClassForm(MyCustomForm):
        # ... additional form fields here

    def clean(self):
        # Then call the clean() method of the super  class
        cleaned_data = super(SubClassForm, self).clean()
        # ... do some cross-fields validation for the subclass 

        # Finally, return the cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks @Mounir. One question though: the way you suggest, `cleaned_data` will contain the fields from the super class. I need to validate fields on the subclass as well. How do I do it?

Comment: to continue my comment, maybe there should be something like: `cleaned_sub_data = self.cleaned_data` followed by `cleaned_data.update(cleaned_sub_data)`. Then I can return `cleaned_data`

Comment: and if you want to raise validation error thats how you do it:

    **raise forms.ValidationError("Your Error")**