# Saving the form while there are two ForeignKeys,

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

I have two models as shown below

```
class college(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
class education(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    school = ForeignKey(college)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startyear = models.IntegerField(blank =True,null = True)
    endyear = models.IntegerField(blank =True,null = True)
```

Views as shown below

```
class EducationListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'education.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return education.objects.filter(author__username=self.request.user.username).order_by('-startyear')
class EducationCreate(CreateView):
    model = dupeducation
    fields = ('school','field','startyear','endyear')
    template_name = 'education_form.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        obj,created = college.objects.get_or_create(name=form['school'])
        obj.save()
        form.instance.school = obj
        return super(EducationCreate, self).form_valid(form)
class EducationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = education
    fields = ('school','field','startyear','endyear')
    template_name = 'education_form.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(EducationUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
class EducationDelete(DeleteView):
    model = education
    success_url = reverse_lazy('education')
```

I am unable to save the form. It's throwing an error to the school field like this "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.".

My goal is to take input for the school field and check that field with get_object_or_create . If that object does not exist, create it and attach it to the school field.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or simply imputing a value that does not exist in the School field?

Comment: It should take care of both the things (User should be able to select from the existing objects of college or if that object does not exist it should create first and then use that to asscociate). Actually, I am using text field for taking the input of school.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug, you'll see that `save()` is not being reached. Your problem is in the [Field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/).

What you need to do is to override the `clean_<field>()` method called before any object is saved.

You can read more about it here: [Django how to override clean() method in a subclass of custom form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231183/django-how-to-override-clean-method-in-a-subclass-of-custom-form)

While overriding `clean_school()`, you will be able to add the value to the database, and later, in `save()`, simply make the attribution.